# Why is dotnet test command line not respecting run settings?

Tags: .net-core

When I use the code coverage option in Visual Studio, I set the runsettings to my custom file and the results only  include the dlls that are specified in my custom file.  However, if I use the command line to run the tests, the code coverage results include all dlls, not just the ones from my run settings file.  What do I need to do to get the command line to respect the runsettings file?

> dotnet.exe test MyTestProj.csproj -l:xunit --collect:"Code Coverage"
> /p:settings=runsettings.runsettings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, `/p:settings=runsettings.runsettings` is not a valid way to set parameters, anymore.  I switched to `--settings:"runsettings.runsettings"`, and now it all works.